# Node JS error 'RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000'

Tags: node.js

I'm following the [Beginners Series to Node JS by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/beginners-series-to-nodejs/?page=2). At 3.47 into [video 18 of 26](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/beginners-series-to-nodejs/how-to-create-a-get-api-with-nodejs-and-express-18-of-26)

my sample code throws 'RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000' whereas the tutorial is successful

Below is my sample code as I followed along. Can you let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks

**file name is App.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Read info user/client sends to server
const package = require('./package.json');

const port = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 5000;
const apiRoot = '/api'; // register the router with the app

const app = express();
// configure app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({origin: /hhtp:\/\/localhost/})); // by default browsers are allowed to access APIs that are on the servere from which the page was rendered
app.options('*', cors()); // using cors allows access from some where else. This allows 1 site to render the client and another to manage the server

// configure routes
const router = express.router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => {   // the '/' is the default path. req = request. res = response
    res.send(`${package.description} - v${package.version}`); 
});

// register routes
// tell app to use registered router with the app
app.use(apiRoot, router) ;  // specify api route and then add in the router

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is up!');
});
```

Comment: Have you started your Express app (seems to be covered in the [previous video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/beginners-series-to-nodejs/how-to-create-a-web-api-with-nodejs-and-express-17-of-26))?

Comment: Video seems out of date. `body-parser` as a separate module is no longer required; it is now built in to Express. Your CORS config is also incorrect. See [the guide in the Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) for a better example

Comment: The Express app was not started. Once started it worked. Thanks for the answer as well as the additional tips on CORS and body-parser